# Google AppEngine Java Web Technologies

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp, frontend

In the last period, I tried to learn something about the Google cloud technology and I quite liked it.

I made a test project for learning GWT bound to GAE, too. In my opinion, the web toolkit is a nice framework for building a Web 2.0 UI from scratch, for those who always worked with Java, but... I think my team is not ready for that, unfortunately.

So, I have to choose another front-end technology, rather than leave my mates writing thousands-code-lines JSP.

What do you recommend to me? Last year I worked a little with Spring MVC and Struts, but since the project we're going to start is a "green field", I'd like to go for a state of art framework.

Remember:

- traditional "page" approach (html views, forms, and so on)
- must work on Google App Engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This link](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/WillItPlayInJava) lists all the supported frameworks on GAE. After going through that list I'd either go with Spring MVC or Struts 1.

[Here is a CRUD tutorial with sprint MVC](http://www.digitalsanctum.com/2009/07/02/google-app-engine-for-java-crud-with-jdo-spring-mvc/) to get you started.

Comment: Thank you, can you point me to a simple tutorial for making some basics things with Spring MVC, e.g. sending a form, navigate some pages, some working examples.

Comment: @FabioB. updated the post with the tutorial link

Comment: nice tut :) what about configuring my environment?

Answer (score 1):

If you have to go with GAE I would stick with GWT (if your devs are good they should be willing to learn :) ), or maybe a simple framework like [apache click](http://www.softwarepassion.com/apache-click-on-google-app-engine-hello-world-example/). Otherwise developing something other than simple Servlet/JSP is a pain even if it doesn't look so at the beginning of the project.

Comment: Apache Click seems nice, thank you. However, why did you think, for example, Spring MVC would be a pain? My devs do are good and willing to learn, but the time window for the project doesn't allow us to take too much time for that.

Comment: I've tried to play with GAE a few times and I can tell you one thing, if its commercial project and it can become complex (so you would need a proper framework like Spring) don't do it on GAE. There are many posts regarding problems on GAE, here is just a one: http://aralbalkan.com/1504

Comment: thank you Kris, but that was 2008, now I hope a lot is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try PLAY (http://www.playframework.org/), watch the video and I think you would be sold.

It supports GAE through a plugin (http://www.playframework.org/modules/gae). It states that it supports GAE 1.4 but we are using the 1.5.3 SDK and it works just fine. You can also use the siena plugin which is a hibernate-like layer for the GAE datastore. You can develop locally (and have the same file-backed datastore and in-memory memcache), once you are done, hit "gae:deploy", enter your email and password and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Let me recommend you using Spring MVC, but using Thymeleaf [http://www.thymeleaf.org] --of which I'm author-- as a view-layer technology instead of JSPs.

This combination will provide you with the *traditional* approach you require (HTML views, forms...) and at the same time will allow you to use a more elegant approach to prototyping and developing your HTML interface.

Good luck with your projects.

Comment: How can you run Thymeleaf (which I'm fan of) on Google AppEngine?

Answer (score 0):

I would try [Jello framework](http://jello-framework.com). It is a Java Application Framework optimized for Google App Engine including comprehensive Data Authorization model, a powerful RESTful engine, and out-of-the-box UI views.